# Jackson collection deserializer to accept empty xml tags

Tags: java, xml, jackson, deserialization

I am facing the following issue.

As a user of XML Jackson library, I would like to know if there is any possibility to deserialize `XML` `List` containing null elements.

Consider the following class:

```
public class TestJacksonList {

List<String> strings;
List<Integer> integers;
List<Path> paths;

public static final ObjectMapper XML_MAPPER = new XmlMapper()
        .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
        .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);


public static TestJacksonList parseXml(String content) throws IOException {
    try {
        TestJacksonList testJacksonList = XML_MAPPER.readValue(content, TestJacksonList.class);
        return testJacksonList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

public List<String> getStrings() {
    return strings;
}

public List<Path> getPaths() {
    return paths;
}

    public List<Integer> getIntegers() {
        return integers;
    }
}
```

I want the following tests to pass:

```
public class TestJacksonListTest {

    @Test
    public void should_deserialize_strings_tags() throws IOException {

        // given
        String inputXml = "<xml>" +
                "<strings>" +
                "<string>hello</string>" +
                "<string>world</string>" +
                "<string></string>" +
                "</strings></xml>";

        // when
        TestJacksonList testJacksonList = TestJacksonList.parseXml(inputXml);

        // then --> OK
        Assertions.assertThat(testJacksonList.getStrings()).hasSize(3).containsOnly("hello", "world", "");
    }


    @Test
    public void should_deserialize_integer_tags() throws IOException {

        // given
        String inputXml = "<xml>" +
                "<integers>" +
                "<integer>12</integer>" +
                "<integer></integer>" +
                "<integer>32</integer>" +
                "</integers></xml>";

        // when
        TestJacksonList testJacksonList = TestJacksonList.parseXml(inputXml);

        // then --> KO
        Assertions.assertThat(testJacksonList.getIntegers()).hasSize(3);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_deserialize_path_tags() throws IOException {

        // given
        String inputXml = "<xml>" +
                "<paths>" +
                "<path>hello</path>" +
                "<path>world</path>" +
                "<path></path>" +
                "</paths></xml>";

        // when
        TestJacksonList testJacksonList = TestJacksonList.parseXml(inputXml);

        // then --> KO
        Assertions.assertThat(testJacksonList.getPaths()).hasSize(3);
    }
}
```

Following are the things that I noticed:

- It's OK for a list representing `String` to contain empty elements. It is later interpreted as empty string (because `Jackson` use the specific `StringCollectionDeserializer`)
- Other list type use the generic `CollectionDeserializer` that does not accept empty tags. It triggers the exception:

  > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
  >   Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of START_OBJECT token
  >   at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6fe7aac8; line: 1, column: 46] (through reference chain: com.altirnao.migrationtools.core.model.configuration.TestJacksonList["integers"]->java.util.ArrayList[1](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html))

I looked into the [`DeserialisationFeature`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html) but none of them seems to match my case.

When the tag is empty I want the `List` to contain `null`.

We may argue that it makes no sens to put an empty tag in a list container tag, but the `XML` I want to parse is modified by non technical users who are inclined to do that.

Last but not least, if the tag is not nested, it can be empty, that is a tag representing a path field can be empty and will be deserialized as null.
I expect the same in a list container.

Comment: [`DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT) is not working for `XML`?

Comment: It was the first one I though to, but oddly enough it is not working.
adding: 
.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
to the mapper still give me the same error.

Comment: it seems https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml in 2.8 version (6 days ago) includes this feature.....

Comment: Yes nice move. But my tests are still failing with 2.8. I am sure I use this version by looking to the called code. It did work for you ?

Comment: nope, just found this discussion https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/162, maybe not implemented yet?

Comment: Ok, thx for the link. I think I will continue this discussion or open a new one to know where this feature is. I let you know in any case :)

Comment: hope you find a solution :)

Comment: not sure this helps, however I found out that explicit specify null works like this `<integer>null</integer>`

Comment: Yeah, but my case is specific to what user can do. I have an application that I configure through an XML file. Since it is the client who provide the XLM (according a template) he/she may leave some empty tags. In his point of view it's normal and expect this tag to be ignored.

Comment: @sharonbn this is a fight with non careful users providing dirty data... I understand OP so much................... sigh `:'(`

Comment: Yeah. We will later force the user to pass through a generator but for the moment I have to deal with it.

Comment: Have you tried using the @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing="...") annotation to specify a custom CollectionDeserializer that handles the missing values?

Comment: Nop. I initially wanted to know if this case was already handled by the library through an annotation or configuration.
Since, when not nested into a list, empty tag are infered as null, It make sens to me to get the same behavior with the generic CollectionDeserializer. In the end I may indeed implements my own deserializer. 
Thx by the way for pointing this annotation I will use in the latter case.